# print 001, 002, ..., 099, 100 instead of 1, 2, 3, ..., 99, 100

Tags: bash, command-line

I want to print 2 numbers that are in the following format: 
001,002,003,...,015,016,017,...,098,099,100

```bash
for i in touch {001..100}; do
        for j in touch {001..100}; do
                if (( $j > $i )); then
                        echo $i $j
                fi
        done
done
```

The loop does what I want it to do.

But the problem is that it prints them without the 0s. For example it prints 1 2, 1 3, 1,4, ..., 99 100. 
And I want it to print 001 002, 001 003, 001 004, ... , 099 100. 
Does anyone have any idea of how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The retention of leading zeros was added in `bash` 4; you appear to be using an older version of `bash`. However, if the 0s *were* retained, you would have to adjust your comparison to avoid treating the values as octal numbers. (`090`, for instance, is an invalid octal number.)

```
for i in {001..100}; do
  for j in {001..100}; do
    if (( 10#$j > 10#$i )); then
      echo $i $j
    fi
  done
done
```

Using `printf` with a C-style `for` loop would be preferable, though.

```
for ((i=1; i < 101; i++)); do
  for ((j=i+1; j < 101; j++)); do
    printf '%03d %03d\n' "$i" "$j"
  done
done
```

Note there is no comparison; the inner loop starts `j` at a value greater than `i`.

Comment: The first section still prints the numbers without the 0s but the printf works. Do you have any idea what's missing for the first one?

Comment: As I said in the first sentence, the version of `bash` you are using appears to be too old; use a newer version of `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use printf:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
        for j in {1..100}; do
                if (( $j > $i )); then
                        printf "%03d %03d\r\n" $i $j
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: Why do you have a carriage return in the output?

Answer (score -1):

Use `seq`:

```
for i in touch $(seq -w 1 100); do
        for j in touch $(seq -w 1 100); do
                if (( $j > $i )); then
                        echo $i $j
                fi
        done
done
```

`printf` could also work.

Comment: I get this error line 10: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Comment: Right. I only tackled the problem you asked for. The issue of comparing the numbers in the proper base was another history.